# Write ExcelFile

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, db2

I have a scenario  where I need to store all data of current workbook including template to a new excel workbook/ worksheet and store that new file to database in BLOB. I am using C#. Any demo available ?

Comment: Why both SQL Server and DB2, out of curiosity

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [Open XML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx) to read and write Excel documents. It can read and write Office 2007 and 2010 compatible documents without the need for Excel to be installed on the machine/server. Another approach would be to automate Excel (instantiate an Excel.Application object, and then programmatically drive Excel to do the work).

I usually recommend option 1.

Comment: I want to do it programmatically using C# with application object. Any tutorial to store whole excel file to db as it is without reading its content ?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. If it is saved on disk, you can read its contents with File.ReadAllBytes and then store those bytes in the DB.

Comment: Lets say there is scenario where you have to store all data of your current sheet to db in such way that when u fetch the data back and put it on new worksheet the template remains preserved. Any way to implement this ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852678/net-excel-library-that-can-read-write-xls-files).

The accepted answer recommends using an open source library called [NPOI](http://code.google.com/p/npoi/) for manipulating spreadsheets.