# Excel biff5 to biff8 conversion

Tags: apache-poi, xls

My system uses Apache-POI to manage some xls files. Now I've got almost 300 xls files, but it appears that they are in an old format so i got this exception:

> The supplied spreadsheet seems to be Excel 5.0/7.0 (BIFF5) format. POI only supports BIFF8 format (from Excel versions 97/2000/XP/2003)

Is there a way to handle that or to automatically convert all those files to a biff8 format?

Comment: What do you want to do with these older files? Read them, or read + change + write?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go with converting it to OOXLS format, POI supports both BIFF8 and newer OOXLS. Download official Microsoft converter pack:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3

Convert files by running `excelcnv.exe -oice <input file> <output file>`. You can try run it directly from your code as external program, or create some batch file. There is a good explanation from **mrdivo** at social msdn [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8becabda-0014-4e06-8354-5f576bf46595/convert-bulk-using-ofcexe).

**EDIT**

The download mentioned above from microsoft.com is no longer available as of 6/21/2018.  However, `excelcnv.exe` is a standard part of some Microsoft Office installations.  It has been confirmed to be deployed with Office 2014 and Office 2016, and possibly other versions.  It can be found at:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16` (or `Office14`).
```

Comment: I found it archived at https://web.archive.org/web/20180403110858/https://download.microsoft.com/download/9/2/2/9222D67F-7630-4F49-BD26-476B51517FC1/FileFormatConverters.exe via https://web.archive.org/web/20180403110918/http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=3 (although I couldn't get it to do anything on Windows 10).

Comment: Possible new DL location (functionality untested): https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=2526297

Answer (score 0):

It seems apache-POI can't handle BIFF5 format.

You should try to use Java Excel API instead : http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/

Comment: This Java Excel API does not have a way to iterate through all the rows/records of the worksheet or to verify how many rows/records a worksheet has. Or am I missing something.