# How to utilize Excel Libraries

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get the correlation coefficients of dataset X and dataset Y from an excel file; dataset X containing 4 columns and Y containing 1. I believe I have to create 5 array variables containing the values of each column.

How do I read and store values in a specific range from an excel file? And how do I correlate them programatically?

I appreciate any enlightening advice. :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852678/net-excel-library-that-can-read-write-xls-files

Comment: @gsharp Thanks.